# jhipster import-jdl use relative path in liquibase master.xml

Tags: jhipster, code-generation, liquibase, relative-path, jdl

`jhipster import-jdl model.jh` by default generates the following tree structure:

```
src/main/resources/config/liquibase
├── authorities.csv
├── changelog
│   ├── 00000000000000_initial_schema.xml
├── master.xml
├── users.csv
└── users_authorities.csv
```

master.xml contains the following:

```
<include 
   file="config/liquibase/changelog/00000000000000_initial_schema.xml" 
   relativeToChangelogFile="false"
/>
```

**Is there a way to get jhipster import-jdl to generate `relativeToChangelogFile="true"`?**

Desired results:

```
<include 
   file="changelog/00000000000000_initial_schema.xml" 
   relativeToChangelogFile="true"
/>
```

jhipster version:

```
$ jhipster --version
Using JHipster version installed globally
5.4.2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not supported through JHipster or JDL.  You will have to change the value manually.